# Regex Pattern to Split Word in A string Using An Identifier

Tags: java, regex

I would like to split the following string by commas using a DOTALL regex pattern what will accept letters, numbers, whitespaces and special characters such as underscores and asterisks i.e. `@input("Test_1, Test_TWO , TEST_THIRTY_3*")` so the output would look like:

```
"Test_1",
"Test_TWO",
"TEST_THIRTY_3*"
```

---

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String line = "@input(\"Test_1,Test_TWO , TEST_THIRTY_3*\"\\)\";
    String pattern = "@input(\"(.*?)\".*";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Found word: " + m.group(1) );
    }
```

Comment: Note that `Pattern.DOTALL` is typically used to match line terminators with the dot - most if not all other characters are already matched without that option required. This said, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to correct the above pattern to use a double quote as a line terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `(` by `\(` so your regex should look like this `@input\(\"(.*?)\".*`, second you can use `\s*,\s*` to split the result like this :

```
String line = "@input(\"Test_1,Test_TWO , TEST_THIRTY_3*\"\\)";
String pattern = "@input\\(\"(.*?)\".*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.group(1).split("\\s*,\\s*")));
    //----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
}
```

outputs

```
[Test_1, Test_TWO, TEST_THIRTY_3*]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to stick to regex you might just take the string methods.

```
List<String> output = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the String i'm trying to identify is stored within another String so i need to use a regex patern using the start tag @input(" and the end tag of a double quote "

Comment: @Orby you could just do it in 2 parts. First regex (or substring) to extract the data in between `@input("` and `"`. Then `string.split(",")` to extract the individual values.